# How to get MAX value with some conditions (SQL)

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Please help me to build a query.

Need to get MAX(LVALUE) & SUM(BVALUE).
It is very simple requirement but there are 3 conditions I should consider as following.

a. If BVALUE is zero, the row should not involve in building MAX(LVALUE).

b. At least one row per NAME should be printed.

c. If all BVALUE is zero, MAX(LVALUE) should be zero.

```
CREATE TABLE P_TEST
(
NAME VARCHAR2(10),
LVALUE NUMBER,
BVALUE NUMBER
)
/

INSERT INTO P_TEST VALUES('FIRST',929292,0);
INSERT INTO P_TEST VALUES('FIRST',12,32);
INSERT INTO P_TEST VALUES('FIRST',-34,0);
INSERT INTO P_TEST VALUES('FIRST',21,0);
INSERT INTO P_TEST VALUES('SECOND',79292,0);
COMMIT;
```

Below query simply works but MAX(LVALUE) 929292 is driven from the zero value of BVALUE so it is out of the rule.

```
SELECT NAME,MAX(LVALUE),SUM(BVALUE)
FROM P_TEST
GROUP BY NAME
/
```

@ Wrong result

```
NAME       MAX(LVALUE) SUM(BVALUE)
---------- ----------- -----------
SECOND       79292       0
FIRST       929292      32
```

@ Desired result

```
NAME       MAX(LVALUE) SUM(BVALUE)
---------- ----------- -----------
SECOND       0       0
FIRST       12      32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregate functions with [FILTER clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) and [coalesce()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to get zeroes for NULL results:

```
select 
    name,
    coalesce(max(lvalue) filter (where bvalue <> 0), 0) as max_lvalue,
    coalesce(sum(bvalue) filter (where bvalue <> 0), 0) as sum_bvalue
from p_test
group by name;

  name  | max_lvalue | sum_bvalue 
--------+------------+------------
 SECOND |          0 |          0
 FIRST  |         12 |         32
(2 rows)
```

You can use CASE expression instead of FILTER if the last is not known in your RDBMS:

```
select 
    name,
    coalesce(max(case when bvalue <> 0 then lvalue end), 0) as max_lvalue,
    coalesce(sum(case when bvalue <> 0 then bvalue end), 0) as sum_bvalue
from p_test
group by name;
```

Comment: Beautiful. That is what I wanted to try.. CASE WHEN. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not considering in calculating the max when BVALUE=0, you can exclude all rows when BVALUE = 0. In all cases, it will not contribute to the SUM(BVALUE) since it is 0

```
select max(lvalue), sum(bvalue)
from p_test
where bvalue != 0
group by name
```

Since you need to show a record for each name, the above will not show a record for "SECOND". To solve this, you can join to self, or use sub-query

```
select nvl(max(b.lvalue), 0), nvl(sum(b.bvalue), 0)
from p_test a, p_test b
where a.name = b.name (+)
and b.bvalue != 0
```

Or (the below allows you to control more on what to include for each summary)

```
select distinct name, 
     nvl((select max(b.lvalue) from p_test b where b.name = a.name and b.bvalue != 0), 0),
     nvl((select sum(c.lvalue) from p_test c where c.name = a.name), 0)
from p_test a
```

Comment: You understand what I wanted fully. It works well. Thank you so much.